# Can I store an object in an arraylist within the same class?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Can I do something like

```
public class Java{
  private ArrayList<Java> javas;

  public void createJava(int size){
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         java.add(new Java());
  }    


}
```

or is it even good practice to do that?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? :)

Comment: It depends how you call `createJava`. Calling it in a Constructor would end in an `StackOverFlow`. Otherwise there shouldn´t be a problem

Comment: Whether it's a good practice depends on the use case.

Comment: At best i's not accurately describing what you have (perhaps intentionally). The flag, IMHO, is your class name and create method is singular but you're in fact creating a collection. Are you sure there's not another class that should have a collection of Javas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reason for it then there is nothing wrong with it. That is how many trees are implemented - a node contains a collection of sub-nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an instance of a class in its own class is necessary to create trees and linked lists. However, except for special situations it should be avoided because it makes code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can implement this, But every class you write implement Java.lang.object.
Hence it does not make any any difference.
But as far as User defined objects are considered the instance is only created to get access to properties or methods of other class.
So try to avoid creating instance of class in its own class.
if you try to do this you will be creating instance within an instance which will be a bad practise of coding

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I get what you're saying but it's definitely not "bad practice" to have an instance within an instance. As noted in another answer it's necessary for Nodes in trees and doubly linked lists to have a left and right Node for a tree Node and previous and next Node for a doubly linked list *inside* a Node.